# Qemu and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ld, qemu

When I exec `qemu-aarch64` with a binary which is using shared libraries I get the following:

```
 qemu-aarch64 -L /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu ./test                                                                                 
 ./test: error while loading shared libraries: testlibrary.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Obviously it is because `test` does not know where the shared libraries are.

Thus:

```
 qemu-aarch64 -L /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu -E LD_PRELOAD="/home/test/libraries/testlibrary.so.1 /home/test/libraries/testlibrary2.so.1" ./test                                                                                 
 hi!
```

Ok, it works; but when I use LD_LIBRARY_PATH it does not work:

```
  qemu-aarch64 -L /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu -E LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/test/libraries ./test                                                                                 
 ./test: error while loading shared libraries: testlibrary.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The difference between LD_PRELOAD and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, from ld.so man:

```
LD_PRELOAD: 
      A list of additional, user-specified, ELF shared objects
      to be loaded before all others.  This feature can be used
      to selectively override functions in other shared objects.

      The items of the list can be separated by spaces or
      colons, and there is no support for escaping either
      separator.  The objects are searched for using the rules
      given under DESCRIPTION.  Objects are searched for and
      added to the link map in the left-to-right order specified
      in the list.

      In secure-execution mode, preload pathnames containing
      slashes are ignored.  Furthermore, shared objects are
      preloaded only from the standard search directories and
      only if they have set-user-ID mode bit enabled (which is
      not typical).

      Within the names specified in the LD_PRELOAD list, the
      dynamic linker understands the tokens $ORIGIN, $LIB, and
      $PLATFORM (or the versions using curly braces around the
      names) as described above in Dynamic string tokens.  (See
      also the discussion of quoting under the description of
      LD_LIBRARY_PATH.)

      There are various methods of specifying libraries to be
      preloaded, and these are handled in the following order:

      (1) The LD_PRELOAD environment variable.

      (2) The --preload command-line option when invoking the
          dynamic linker directly.

      (3) The /etc/ld.so.preload file (described below).
```

And,

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
      A list of directories in which to search for ELF libraries
      at execution time.  The items in the list are separated by
      either colons or semicolons, and there is no support for
      escaping either separator.  A zero-length directory name
      indicates the current working directory.

      This variable is ignored in secure-execution mode.

      Within the pathnames specified in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, the
      dynamic linker expands the tokens $ORIGIN, $LIB, and
      $PLATFORM (or the versions using curly braces around the
      names) as described above in Dynamic string tokens.  Thus,
      for example, the following would cause a library to be
      searched for in either the lib or lib64 subdirectory below
      the directory containing the program to be executed:

          $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$ORIGIN/$LIB' prog

      (Note the use of single quotes, which prevent expansion of
      $ORIGIN and $LIB as shell variables!)
```

Why does it work with LD_PRELOAD and not with LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 0):

The library you're opening with LD_PRELOAD is "testlibrary.so.1", but the library that the dynamic loader otherwise looks for is "testlibrary.so.3", which suggests there's a mismatch between the library version you have and the library version the binary is linked against, which maybe the LD_PRELOAD is side-stepping. Does LD_LIBRARY_PATH work if you make sure that you have the file in that directory that the binary is looking for ?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typing error. "testlibrary.so.x" are examples. I have updated the question fixing it. Answering to your question LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not work but LD_PRELOAD yes, all library files are in /home/test/libraries/